# Error mysqlimport loading to symlink table

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-8.0

Getting `ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 168 - 'Unknown (generic) error from engine'` when trying to import a .sql file produced via mysqldump.  Running MySQL 8 on a Ubuntu 22.04 system.

```
chris@chris-X1C6:/media/chris/T7$ sudo mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u admin -p -D op < op_prices.sql
Enter password:
ERROR 1030 (HY000) at line 25: Got error 168 - 'Unknown (generic) error from engine' from storage engine
```

Getting the following after trying to do the import within a MySQL session:

```
mysql> use op; 
Database changed 
mysql> source /media/chris/T7/op_prices.sql 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
    
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 168 - 'Unknown (generic) error from engine' from storage engine Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'op.prices' doesn't exist 
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'op.prices' doesn't exist 
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'op.prices' doesn't exist 
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'op.prices' doesn't exist
```

`op.prices` is the table I'm loading from the .sql file.  `op` is the db I've created for this with symlink in datadir to external drive.  For clarity, using [this process](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/symbolic-links-to-databases.html) to create the symlink.

Don't see anything in the log file.  Have turned symbolic links on in MySQL 8.  Changed permissions on the link and linked to directory on external drive such that mysql has ownership.

What am I missing?

**Edit (adding top portion of .sql; adding more output was just a wall of data):**

```
chris@chris-X1C6:/media/chris/T7$ head -n 54 op_prices.sql
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.36, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: op
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.36

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `prices`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `prices`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `prices` (
  `dataDate` date NOT NULL,
  `ticker` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `optionSymbol` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `expDate` date NOT NULL,
  `type` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `strike` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `last` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `bid` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `ask` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `OI` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `IV` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `delta` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `gamma` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `theta` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `vega` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `aka` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `dataDate` (`dataDate`,`ticker`,`expDate`,`type`),
  KEY `optionSymbol` (`optionSymbol`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `prices`
--

LOCK TABLES `prices` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `prices` DISABLE KEYS */;
```

Comment: so open the sql file and show the 10th command

Comment: @nbk, didn't realize it could be read as a text file...updated.

Comment: that is not the 10 th command you posted only 3. the data you sanitiz, as long as the structure of the data keeps intact

Comment: @nbk, it's thousand of lines long...even taking just the next row

Comment: @nbk, so just running each step, the `CREATE TABLE` call is the one throwing the error I'm seeing

Comment: as you see in your import the 10th command produces the problem, so that is what we need to see

Comment: @nbk, it's not...when I run just the `CREATE TABLE` from above I get the error I'm seeing.  What's this indicate?  Particularly in the context of a symlink to datadirectory on an external drive